# What kind of values can "Duration" accept in Rally?

Tags: rally

I am using the RallyRestAPI and ideally I want to pass to a test case I am creating through the API a duration time in this format "MM:SS".  I am passing for example, "9:45" (9 minutes, 45 seconds), but I get an error that .."9:45 cannot convert to a double".  Does the duration field in Rally only accept double values or what other type of values can it accept?  Thanks.

My code is something like this:

```
DynamicJsonObject tcresults = new DynamicJsonObject();

// ...

tcresults["Duration"] = "9:45";
```

I get the error when doing this line below:

```
CreateResult cr = _RallyApi.Create(_workspace, "TestCaseResults", tcresults);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the web service docs [here](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) it has to be a double.  So "9:45" would be 9.75 instead.